# How to delete a row in postgresql before insert from csv/txt

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a large file text file (100k rows, x columns, delimiter is ';') into postgresql 9.6, pgadmin4, in windows 10 using

```
COPY my_table FROM 'E:\DATA\my_file.txt' (DELIMITER(';');
```

A small number of rows in the text file do have more than x columns; as a result I get the “ERROR: extra data after last expected column” message. This is due to things like `; ; ;`

I am looking for a way to detect those rows and delete them with something like a trigger instead of insert.

Thanks for your quick answer, but is there a way to clean the data with postgresql? 
I am thinking of something like (pseudocode) :

```
CREATE my_table(x columns);
CREATE funtion import_csv(csv_file,my_table){
    for i = 1 to count_rows(csv_file){
        if count_columns.csv_file.row(i)<>x{
            Skip csv_file.row(i);
        }else{
            insert csv_file.row(i) in my_table;
        }
    }
}
```

or something similar with Delete instead of Skip.

Thanks

Comment: Thinking you might need to "clean" the data file using Python or something else prior to copying the data into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to preview a data before loading to database in this case?

Take a tool to work with CSV files and load data into it. Personally I prefer [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) data analysis labrary (of course it can do much-much more!), but it's method [.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is realized very well:

```
$ cat err.csv
0.0;0.7;0.29
1.0;0.23;0.55
0.0;0.72;0.42;-1;-3.4
0.0;;0.98;0.68
0.0;0.48;0.39;0;8
1.0;0.34;0.73
0.0;0.44;0.06
1.0;0.4;0.74
0.0;0.18;0.18
1.0;0.53;0.53

$ python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.read_csv('err.csv', header=None, sep=';', names='ABCDEFGH')
>>> df
     A     B     C     D    E   F   G   H
0  0.0  0.70  0.29   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  1.0  0.23  0.55   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  0.0  0.72  0.42 -1.00 -3.4 NaN NaN NaN
3  0.0   NaN  0.98  0.68  NaN NaN NaN NaN
4  0.0  0.48  0.39  0.00  8.0 NaN NaN NaN
5  1.0  0.34  0.73   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
6  0.0  0.44  0.06   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
7  1.0  0.40  0.74   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
8  0.0  0.18  0.18   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
9  1.0  0.53  0.53   NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

`NaN` is absent value. Here you may look how your CSV-file was interpreted. If you wish you may drop some lines, fill absent values and so on. Please, have a look at pandas documentation - this tool is quite powerful to tinker with data.

When you are sure you have right data, you may write it back to csv file with [.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method or directly [.to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

As a last resort you may iterate over rows, and perform some operations with them. But I do not recommend this way, especially for big tables:

```
>>> for row in df.iterrows():
...     print(row)
...
...
(0, A    0.00
B    0.70
C    0.29
D     NaN
E     NaN
F     NaN
G     NaN
H     NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64)
(1, A    1.00
B    0.23
C    0.55
D     NaN
E     NaN
F     NaN
G     NaN
H     NaN
Name: 1, dtype: float64)
# ...... and so on .....
```

Comment: The file indeed looks a lot like your exemple:

    0.0;0.7;John;0.29
    1.0;0.23;Mike;0.55
    0.0;0.72;;Jane;;-3.4
    0.0;0.98;Gil;0.68
    0.0;0.48;;;0
    1.0;0.34;Karl;0.73
    0.0;0.44;James;0.06
    1.0;0.4;Kiki;0.74
    0.0;0.18;Albert;0.18
    1.0;0.53;Mark;0.53

I do not wish to preview the files as they are too large(more than 100k rows), but it would be great if one can use Pandas to recognise the third and fifth row in this example(more than 4 rows), delete/move them and then write the data back to csv with .to_csv().
Thanks  for the tip. I will take into it.

Comment: Look at option `warn_bad_lines` - it will ignore bad lines and warn you about them/

Answer (score 0):

> This is due to things like ; ; ;

Where are they from? Should be there values? If they are used as a symbol ";" not a delimiter, you'll get corrupted data. Some columns can appear in other places and so on. 
You can rewrite you file into INSERTs, on feed it into Postgres line-by-line, but chances to get messed data are very high.

Comment: They are mostly used as delimiter, but sometimes as symbol. Those rows do indeed have columns that appear on the wrong place.
Since the amount of corrupted rows is less than 10 per 100k, I prefer to delete them or place them in an error table as string. 
Do you have maybe an example code of what you mean by “ You can rewrite you file into INSERTs, on feed it into Postgres line-by-line”?

Comment: Best solution - re-export this CSV with escaped ";" symbols? May be you have source data or smth alike to reexport?